# Don't upload more than 10mb primefaces

Tags: jsf, file-upload, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm having problem and it look's simple, but I don't find a answer...Maybe someone could help me?
I'm using fileUpload from primefaces 5.0 and I can't do uploads of files that have more than 10mb... One file with 9.9mb works fine! =o

What I need to change to increase this limit?

Codes:

```
<p:fileUpload multiple="false"  cancelLabel="Cancelar" label="Selecionar Brasão..." fileUploadListener="#{back.uploadArquivo}" mode="advanced" dragDropSupport="true" auto="false" 
         fileLimit="1" sizeLimit="51380224"    update="panel_grid_upload_arquivo, :growl" />
```

backBean:

```
  public void uploadArquivo(FileUploadEvent event) {
    DocumentoEntity arquivo = new DocumentoEntity();
    try {
        arquivo.setArquivo(IOUtils.toByteArray(event.getFile().getInputstream()));
        arquivo.setNomeArquivo(event.getFile().getFileName());
        arquivo.setNome(event.getFile().getFileName());
        this.arquivo = arquivo;
        exibirMensagemSucesso("Upload feito com sucesso", "O arquivo agora está associado ao documento");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        exibirMensagemErro("Ocorreu algum erro", "Ocorreu algum erro e o upload não pôde ser feito");
        LOGGER.error("Não realizou o upload do arquivo");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

web.xml:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

A file with more than 10mb don't reach the BackBean...
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I discover the problem after some hours... and was really so simple. This happened because Wildfly 8! I need to put max-post-size="50485760" in the standalone.xml and now works fine.

```
<server name="default-server">
            <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http" max-post-size="50485760"/>
            <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
            </host>
        </server>
```